# Alter all user profile link

Tags: navigation

I am using Drupal commons distribution for a community site. The site has many private groups. When a user is browsing a private group and they click on a profile link (or user picture linking to profile) it will currently take them to the standard profile page, ie:

/users/joe-smith

I want the user to instead be directed to:

/groups/the-green-family/users/joe-smith

This will allow me to display the user profile without making the user feel like they left the group pages.

I can figure out how to handle the custom profile page, but how do I alter all of the user profile links? I tried hook_link_alter but it doesn't seem to be processes. What hook should I be using to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: User links are defined in user_menu(). You could use hook_menu_alter() to insert your own custom function as a page callback that redirects the link according to group context. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7

Comment: Thanks but I still a little lost. I tried: 

function vauzo_general_menu_alter(&$items) {

  $items['user']['access callback'] = '_custom_user_url';
}

/**
* Callback to custom user link
*/
function _custom_user_url(){
  return 'test/url';
}

but its not working and i can't seem to find any useful examples.

Comment: "access callback" determines who has access to the menu link. What you want is the "page callback" - ie $items['user']['page callback']